# How do I give a slider thumb fluid movement?

Tags: html, css

I have a slider with 3 values that moves in steps of 1. I want the movement between each step to be smooth.

Here is what I thought would work:

HTML

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" value="1" class="slider">
```

CSS

```
.slider {
  display: inherit;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.05s
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.05s
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pcoledesign/5f1k4xLt/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `<input type="range" min="1" max="3" step=".1" value="1" class="slider">`

Comment: If it moves in steps of 0.1 I don't think I would be able to add a function to run depending on the range values of 1 to 3, right?